# Generic Add method in class composed of multiple lists

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class composed of multiple lists and I have generic methods to allow me to do CRUD (and other) operations over those lists.

I'm basically trying to do a variation of `DbContext.Set<T>` with `List`.

This is my situation:

```
public class A
{
    private IList<B> Bs;
    private IList<C> Cs;

    public A()
    {
        Administrators = new List<B>();
        Developers = new List<C>();
    }

    public void Add<T>(T entity)
    {
        var propertyIWant = this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetType() == typeof(IList<T>));
        var propertyAsList = propertyIWant as List<T>;
        propertyAsList.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete<T>(T entity)
    {
       //Same idea 
    }

    //Other methods
}
```

The problem is that my code gives me a list of the desired type, but no the *actual* list (i.e. the property).
So any modifications to that list don't modify the property.

I'd like to be able to do something akin to `A.List<T>` to get the list of that type (like `DbContext` can do with `DbContext.Set<T>`).

Comment: Well, for starters, I would advise to use meaningful names for your classes. A, B and C are not meaningful nor descriptive. Your future self will thank me for this. Second, Does B and C have a common interface?

Comment: That is probably something that could be done using a `MemberExpression` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: My first senstation as soon as I readed this is, why would you want to do that? Why not simply expose both internal list as read-only properties and let callers manipulate them directly? Also, you can't read the stored items from client code, and your current approach impedes the usage of two list of the same type.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I changed the names to post them here. Should've changed them to foo, bar, etc.

Comment: @thehennyy Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Alejandro In the future the implementation will probably change. While it's not in the example posted, this class is implementing an interface to allow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a few mistakes here.

1. `Bs` and `Cs` are fields, not properties, so you should use `GetFields`.
2. `Bs` and `Cs` are private, so you should use the binding flags `NonPublic` and `Instance`
3. The result you get from `Where` is an `IEnumerable<T>`. You should call `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` to get a single field info.
4. After getting the field info, you need to call `GetValue` to get the field's value.
5. `p.GetType()` returns `typeof(FieldInfo)`, not the declared type of the field. You should use `FieldType` instead.

Here is the fixed version:

```
public void Add<T>(T entity)
{
    var fieldIWant = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.FieldType == typeof(IList<T>)).SingleOrDefault();
    if (fieldIWant != null) {
        var value = (IList<T>)fieldIWant.GetValue(this);
        value.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

Or, as thehennyy said in the comments, you should probably look into expression trees, specifically `MemberExpression`s to do this. Reflection is quite slow.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sweeper.
Regarding the slowness of reflection, I'm going to add the fields to a cache so I'll only have to look them up once.